# Filter viewController

Tags: swift, search, filter, viewcontroller

In my app I have a search bar where people can add free text and get the results the meet the criteria

```
func search(searchClinics: [Clinica], searchArr: [String]) -> [Clinica] {
    var searchArr = searchArr
    // base case - no more searches - return clinics found
    if searchArr.count == 0 {
        return searchClinics
    }
    // iterative case - search clinic with next search term and pass results to next search
    let foundClinics = searchClinics.filter { item in
        (item.name.lowercased() as AnyObject).contains(searchArr[0]) ||
        item.specialty1.lowercased().contains(searchArr[0]) ||
        item.specialty2.lowercased().contains(searchArr[0])
    }
    // remove completed search and call next search
    searchArr.remove(at: 0)
    return search(searchClinics: foundClinics, searchArr: searchArr)
}
```

I also have a flag to identify if the searchBar is being used

```
var searching = false // Checks if searchBar was used
```

In case searchBar was used, it returns the filtered array data otherwise returns the full list. For example

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        let totalClinics = clinicsSearch.count
        if totalClinics == 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return totalClinics
        }
    } else {
        let totalClinics = clinics.count
        if totalClinics == 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return totalClinics
        }
    }
}
```

I'm now willing to add another viewController where the user would be able to define specific filters (like State, City, Specialty among others). Once the user clicks apply, it would go back to the previous viewController with filtering data.

I'm in doubt with the best approach to apply this filter. At first I though about doing something like:

1. User clicks a button in the navigationBar and opens "Search" viewController;
2. User inputs Data;
3. User clicks "Apply";
4. Call previous viewController;
5. I would add another status flag with status "True" that will be used in my tableView ViewController. If true, considers the list of clinics with filters applied. If not, show the full list of clinics;

I've a lot of searching in stackoverflow but I found a lot of filtering/searchbar stuff but none related to a separate search/filter viewController.
Would you recommend this approach or is there a better way to do it?
One of my concerns here if with step 4... if I call a segue, wouldn't I be stacking views and consuming more memory?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a custom delegate to pass filter data to the previous view controller

Comment: thanks @Cerlin. I liked the idea and I'll study how to implement using delegate

Answer (score 0):

In my app user click filter button present Controller open

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchFilter") as! SearchFilter
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
vc.SearchCompletion = {(model,flag) in
    if(flag){
        self.serachArr.removeAllObjects()
        for i in 0..<model.count{
            self.serachArr.add(ListModel(data: model[i] as! NSDictionary))
        }
        self.ListTable.reloadData()

    }
}
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

User click apply button and  pass data previous Viewcontroller

```
self.SearchCompletion(dataArr,true)
```

Comment: thanks @Tanjima Kothiya. I believe the Delegate method might be better for my case